# scp command for copying to local computer

Tags: scp

I want to copy a couple of `.txt` files from a server using `scp`, but I get a "permission denied" error. I have the password for the server and when I directly connect to their server the password works, but whan I use `scp` for transferring the data, I get permission denied! I use the following command:

```
scp -r user@server:/opt/drop/PATH /path/to/localdir
Error: Permission denied
```

Comment: Your edit should include code blocks (highlight the text and press CTRL+K) and the  exact error message you get.

Comment: What does "when directly want to enter their server" mean?  `ssh` to the server?  What are the file and directory permissions on `remote:/opt/drop/PATH` and `local:/path/to/localdir` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have permission to destination path `/path/to/localdir` otherwise you will get `permission denied`

the fully command syntax is like this:

```
scp sourceuser@sourcehost:/path/to/source/file destinationuser@destinationhost:/path/to/destination/
```

Comment: I have access to the target because usinf sftp I cen open it and see the files there.

Comment: you should have access to both path, source `/opt/drop/PATH` and dest `/path/to/localdir`

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
scp -r user@server:/opt/drop/PATH /path/to/localdir
```

Comment: It is already like this.

Comment: Not according to your post.  Your post is like this: `scp -r USER:/opt/drop/PATH TO MY FOLDER` . Which is incorrect for several reasons.

Comment: BTW the problem is about the password!

Comment: Please edit your original post to include more detailed information that is accurate.

Comment: If you know what the problem is don't post here.  You haven't listened to any suggestions above yet so when you are ready to take advice let us know and maybe we can work this out.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody else has mentioned this (in an answer) yet:

Ensure that you have permission to read the source (input) file(s).

- After connecting to the server with `ssh`, try to read the files, with

  - `cat`, and/or
  - `grep`, and/or
  - `wc`, and or
  - whatever program you like (that reads file(s))
- Try `scp -r user@server:/opt/drop/PATH /tmp`
  or `scp -r user@server:/opt/drop/PATH .`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have permissions to write to the target directory. For example:

```
touch /path/to/localdir/testfile
```

If that returns an error (and I am almost certain it will), you know it's not a problem with SCP.

Comment: I have access to the target because usinf sftp I cen open it and see the files there.

Comment: Seeing the files is different than writing new files. Were you able to run the 'touch' command I mentioned above?